# Ubuntu 14.10 no desktop after kernel update to 3.18.1

Tags: unity, launcher, ccsm

Using 14.10 with an ATI Radeon 5450 graphic card.

Everything was working fine after installing ubuntu 14.10. Then 1 or 2 weeks ago after a normal update, some applications started crashing (thunderbird, firefox, eclipse and sometimes also chrome). 
To solve the crashes, I decided to update the kernel to 3.18.1 and see if it improves it.

Now, I no longer see the desktop (no launcher bar, no unity bar etc). The only thing I get is the wallpaper and the mouse.

Ctr+Alt+T doesn't work nor right click on the desktop.

I know that there are many similar problems on the net but none of the solutions worked for me (I'm trying for many hours now).

Solutions I've tried with no success:

Using Ctr+Alt+F1

1. uninstall and reinstall fglrx
2. `export DISPLAY=:0 
   ccsm`

   Enabled the openGL and unity plugin.

   **Important**: The window of the ccsm did not have any title bar and could not be dragged !!
3. Installed gnome, logged into ubuntu using gnome and got the same empty desktop.
4. Tried re-installing compiz, ccsm, unity desktop, unity.
5. `sudo dconf reset -f /org/compiz/`

   than making sure using `export DISPLAY=:0 and ccms` that the openGL and unity are still checked.

When running `sudo unity` I'm getting an error:

```
...
...
compiz (core) - Error: Plugin 'opengl' not loaded
```

6.

Installed the open graphic drivers

Removed fglrx

`dconf reset -f /org/compiz/`

and

`setsid unity`

Restarted lightdm and got everything back. I was happy and everything worked fine for two hours until ubuntu crashed and does not start anymore. It now shows a black screen with only a cursor which probably means that also the open drivers are not good.

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot (:

**UPDATE**

The crashing was due to a hardware problem. The memory cards where somehow not sitting correctly in their slots. I could not even install from the Live CD because it was crashing with different kernel panic errors every time.

After testing the memory cards one by one and fixing them back correctly, everything worked and I installed a fresh Ubuntu 14.10 (I had to do it because of all the half crashed installation tries). Everything works fine now.

So the solution to the drivers problem was actually solved after installing the open drivers as suggested by  Νίκος Φυτίλης

I'm going to add an answer and signed it as the correct answer

Hope it helps someone (:

Comment: did you try unity --reset ?

Comment: unity --reset is deprecated. I've tried  sudo unity --replace and got the same compiz 'plugin opengl not loaded'.

Comment: lol oups hadn't used unity in a while. sry for useless comment.

Comment: also the fglrx doesnt work (i think) with the new 3.18 kernel. try the open drivers for that kernel from this ppa: https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers

Comment: @Νίκος Φυτίλης Thnaks. I've added the ppa and updated the sys. Also removed fglrx.

Comment: @Νίκος Φυτίλης Thnaks. I've added the ppa and updated the sys. Also removed fglrx. When logging into ubuntu the desktop screen is now the basic wallpaper screen (not my wallpaper). I've checked using ´lspci -nnk | grep -i vga -A3 | grep 'in use'´ which driver is in use and the result was: 'kernel driver in use:radeon'. So it should be ok. BUT when I check 'glxinfo' I get 'Error: unable to open display'. Any ideas?

Comment: It worked, thanks. I've added the details to my question.

Comment: thanks but if someone answers correctly please upvote the comment / answer :). Also please dont update your question with the solution but rather, create an answer and select it as accepted answer so others can see them.

Comment: OK, thanks for clearing it up. I don't see a way to upvote a comment, just an answer and yours was a comment (:. Anyway, I was happy too early as ubuntu crashed after 2 hours of use because an error in the drivers. It doesn't start anymore and shows just a black screen with a cursor. I will try installing the fglrx from the recovery menu. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering my own question.

First, I installed the open graphic drivers as suggested by Νίκος Φυτίλης

```
HOW? WHAT IS THE ACTUAL COMMAND?
```

Afterward, I removed fglrx, but I still didn't get the desktop bars (unity and the top bars).

```
sudo apt-get remove fglrx                                                       
sudo apt-get install fglrx
```

I wanted to reset compiz but got some errors that the display is not found because I was using the only accessible terminal  Ctr+Alt+F1

So after using `export DISPLAY=:0` before reseting compiz, everything came back (:.

```
export DISPLAY=:0
sudo dconf reset -f /org/compiz/  <<<<<<<<<<<<< THIS COMMAND DOES NOT WORK FOR ME?
sudo setsid unity
```

Restarting lightdm...

```
sudo service lightdm restart
```

... brought everything back (:

Answer (score 0):

After the updataion of Kernel if we find any difficulties try with updating the GRUB using the below command,

```
sudo update-grub
sudo reboot
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I was running it after the kernel update and tried it again now just to make sure. It did not help. I also tried running ubuntu using the old kernel 3.16 and got the same empty desktop.